# PHP require_once '...........';

Tags: php

I am calling the function `require_once '../autoload.php';` but I get the error

```
Warning: require_once(../autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\Autotask\vendor\test.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\Autotask\vendor\test.php on line 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: you have bad path to `autoload` file.

Comment: It` s on the same level so  `require_once 'autoload.php'`

Comment: Try giving absolute path instead of relative path, like require_once ABSPATH . 'autoload.php';

Comment: Oh, remove the "../" before autoload.php

Comment: Could you please post a copy of your code, rather than a screenshot. It makes it easier for people to answer your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To avoid this type of problems, and for best practice, i advice to use the root path:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

The code above will assign to $root your realpath on the server.

After that just use the require/include etc according to your localhost/webserver root :

```
require_once($root/Api/Autotask/vendor/autoload.php)
```

For example, if your file is located in websiterootfolder/php/nice_folder
Your code will be :

```
require_once($root/php/nice_folder/autoload.php)
```

By using this practice, you can include any file from whatever position and any way you want, dynamic or not